# How do you convert a matrix into a string?

Tags: python, matrix

let's say I have this matrix: `m = [[0 for i in range(5)] for i in range(5)]`,
which when printed, outputs this:

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

How do I make it so that it outputs something like this:

```
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
```

Comment: `print('\n'.join(' '.join(str(x) for x in row) for row in m))` based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27140283/15497888) by [Michael Laszlo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4275347)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply unpack the list

```
m = [[0 for i in range(5)] for i in range(5)]
for i in m:
    print(*i)
```

Output:

```
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below where `m` is your matrix and can control the spacing in the `' '.join()`

```
for line in m:
 print (' '.join(map(str, line)))
```